# Run Pentaho Job or transformation on Carte Server via command line

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pdi, spoon

I need to call the jobs/trans to run via command line, and therefore I use pan.sh and kitchen.sh to trigger them to run.

However it creates a separate JVM whenever it is triggered. I am considering if it can use the Carte server embedded in the Pentaho Server directly.

Both repositories.xml under home/user/.kettle/ and salve-server-config.xml under server installation folder has been configured.

Somebody has a similar query, but unfortunately the link in the answer is borken.
[Running multiple Kettle transformation on single JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35275791/running-multiple-kettle-transformation-on-single-jvm)

May I know how to run pan.sh and kitchen.sh on the Carte server via command line?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Pentaho Carte provides you with a list of APIs endpoint to execute Jobs (.kjb) or Transformations (.ktr) and use CURL or POSTMAN or any preferred tool. Below is the sample examples

- Executing Transformation:

`curl -x POST http://<carte server>:<host>/kettle/executeTrans/?trans=<name of the transformation> -u 'cluster:cluster'`

- Executing Job:

`curl -x POST http://<carte server>:<host>/kettle/executeJob/?job=<name of the job> -u 'cluster:cluster'`

You can read more about Working with Pentaho Carte Servers using Spoon, CURL, Postman and Airflow [in this blog post](https://tech-spaghetti.com/2023/12/02/working-with-pentaho-carte-server/).

The official Pentaho Carte API documentation links are below:

- [Carte for Transformations](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/020)
- [Carte for Jobs](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/030)
- [Carte for Managing Server](https://help.hitachivantara.com/Documentation/Pentaho/Data_Integration_and_Analytics/9.4/Developer_center/REST_API_Reference/Carte/010)